# Workbook.getWorkbook() error in JExcel API

Tags: java, eclipse, excel

I am using JExcel API for reading a .xls file in Eclipse. Here is my code:

```
import jxl.*;
import java.io.File;

public class JExcelDemoClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Workbook wrk1=new Workbook.getWorkbook("C:\\Test.xls");
            Sheet sheet1=wrk1.getSheet(0);
            Cell col1row1=sheet1.getCell(0,0);
            Cell col1row2=sheet1.getCell(0,1);
            Cell col1row3=sheet1.getCell(0,2);
            String get_col1row1=col1row1.getContents();
            String get_col1row2=col1row2.getContents();
            String get_col1row3=col1row3.getContents();
            System.out.println(get_col1row1);
            System.out.println(get_col1row2);
            System.out.println(get_col1row3);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    }
}
```

When i try to run this code, Eclipse gives me error

**Workbook.getWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type**
Any idea why I am getting this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of this line is wrong:

```
Workbook wrk1=new Workbook.getWorkbook("C:\\Test.xls");
```

you are trying to use `new` on a static method of the `Workbook` class. The correct syntax is:

```
Workbook wrk1 = Workbook.getWorkbook("C:\\Test.xls");
```

(no `new` keyword)

Comment: Why can't I find `Workbook.getWorkbook` ? 
When I say Workbook. I instead get some constants like this `Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of creating workbooks in JExcel. Both require `File` objects.

A non-writable workbook:

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:\\file2.xls"));
```

or by creating a writable workbook with

```
WritableWorkbook writableWorkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("D:\\file1.xls"));
```

Workbook itself is an abstract class that allows different method with different return types (WritableWorkbooks and Workbooks).

`getWorkbook` and `createWorkbook` are use the Factory Pattern

Check out the Java Docs for more information on JExcel

Comment: Why can't I find `Workbook.createWorkbook` ? 
When I say Workbook. I instead get some constants like this `Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG`

Comment: @Muddz I've long since stopped using JExcel, and even Java at work. The latest version does say there's one [here](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/index.html) but only on the concrete `WritableWorkbook`.